# SQL Server - Transaction Log Management

Tags: sql-server

Just wanted to clarify if someone can please advise:

Let's say we have Transaction Log file which was initially set to 4GB, and autogrowth set by increment of 10%. Now Transaction Log has grown to 40GB.

Question: Does transaction log backup will truncate the tlog once completed, means then the tlog will be back to 4GB or 40GB (but now 36gb is available for reuse)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the file will never shrink it is re-used and is circular in nature. A main .ldf(transaction log file) consists out of smaller files called virtual log files or VLF's. These are reused internally to the LDF when they are empty. If all VLF are full the log file will grow by adding new VLF's at the end of the LDF file. So by having a percentage auto growth you also probably have log file fragmentation which can be a performance killer.

If you run the command DBCC LOGINFO you will get a result set with the status of all the virtual log files in the main file. These VLF are essentially used over and over again. Remember it is circular in nature.

So when you start a transaction it is written to a VLF and when it is committed it is marked as complete on the VLF. If you are running your database in simple recovery mode on every checkpoint these committed VLF files are cleaned up and ready for re-use. If your database is in any other recovery mode these VLF are not cleaned up even if they are commited. When you do a transaction log backup these VLF are written to the transaction log backup and then cleaned out. This is how transaction log files are able to replay commited transactions.

However the LDF file that contains these VLF are never shrunk. You really should read the following blog it is a awesome place to really understand the transaction log:

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/8-steps-to-better-transaction-log-throughput/

There are some very detailed articles about this so go read the above link it is excellent.

Comment: Sigh I get downvoted without a constructive comment... please add a comment on why you downvoted. I am grown up and can handle criticism.

Answer (score -2):

No. it will not. Backup won't truncate log. Did you try shrink it?

Comment: So how can i know that out of that 40GB, 36gb is available for re-use now bcos I did TLog backup. Also when TLOG shrink should be done

Comment: You should shrink before you do backup, each time you perform shrink action file will reduce to 1mb+. If not mistaken, you set 4gb for the log file ,it just allocated 4gb for the log file and that does not mean used up 4 gb. You could check from your ldf physical file to see what is the actual size after shrink

Comment: Never ever shrink you transaction log file. That is bad practise. It  means your probably dont understand recovery modes. If your log file is growing rapidly and you DONT need transaction log backups make sure you are running in simple recovery mode. If you need TRANSACTION LOG Backups and you shrink the file you destroy the transaction log backup chain.

Comment: Transaction log will be reduced when you do transaction log backup.